# how to use/install gps python library

Tags: python, python-2.7, gps

```
root@raspberrypi:~# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 13 2013, 11:20:46)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gps import gps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name gps
>>> exit ()
```

it doesn't seem to work.
Installed debian packages:
gpsd, gpsd-clients, python-gps, libgps20, libgps-dev

Comment: the command "pydoc modules" does return "gps"

Comment: Does `import gps` work?

Comment: Yes, "import gps" works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it on an Ubuntu machine and it worked just fine:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gps import gps
>>>
```

First, make sure the file following files are present (save a directory being different due to be different):

```
/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gps/packet.so
/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gps/clienthelpers.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gps-3.6.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gps/misc.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gps/client.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gps/fake.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gps/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gps/gps.py
```

This can be done by running:

```
dpkg -L python-gps
```

Also make sure there's no `gps.py` laying around in the directory you're running python from as that might screw the importer up.

Comment: That was the exact problem.
My own script had its filename as "gps.py" I would never imagined that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to add that even after removing gps.py, I had a file called gps.pyc which was also creating this problem. u remove this file and then problem vanishes..